# Type signature for index in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-signature

Project Euler Problem 7: What is the 10 001st prime number?

This is a function that takes a single parameter (10001) and returns the 10001st prime.  GHCi gives me no problems:

```
p007nthPrime x = primes !! (x - 1)
    where
        primes :: [Integer]
        primes = sieve [2..]
            where
                sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

Now, being a good Haskeller, I'd like to make a type signature.  However, putting `p007nthPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> a` at the top throws me this error:

```
projecteuler.hs:81:29:
    Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'
    Expected type: Int
      Actual type: a
    In the first argument of `(-)', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `(x - 1)'
    In the expression: primes !! (x - 1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

and inserting `p007nthPrime :: (Num a) => a -> a` does the same thing.  What is the right type signature for this function?

Comment: Well, `!!` has the type `[a] -> Int -> a` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-); the index is of fixed type `Int`. Thus, your function must have the type `(Integral a) => Int -> a`.

Comment: Just have ghci tell you what the type signature is with `:type p007nthPrime `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(!!)` list indexing operator only takes `Int`s, while your `primes` list contains `Integer`s, so your signature needs to be

```
p007nthPrime :: Int -> Integer
```

Both `Int` and `Integer` are types of the class `Integral`, but a single type cannot be both `Int` and `Integer`.

If you need the argument to also be `Integer`, I suggest using the `fromIntegral` function.

Otherwise, to find out what type signature to give a function/value, a good idea is to use the `:t` command in GHCi:

```
*Main> :t p007nthPrime
p007nthPrime :: Int -> Integer
```

Comment: For indexing with `Integer`s and other `Integral` types, Haskell also provides [genericIndex](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex) of type `Integral i => [a] -> i -> a`.